# dropzone.js in laravel application

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, laravel

I am using dropzone.js in laravel application and I want to push the name file uploaded in the array  to store it in cookie but that not executes and not the array has the last file uploaded not all file can any one tell me what the problem

```
class UploadController extends Controller
{


   public $file_request = array();


    public function upload_file_request(Request $request){
        try{


        $file = $request->file('dzfile');

         $email_file = 'file_request_'.time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();;

        $file->storeAs('file_request', $email_file);

       // $array = Arr::prepend($this->file_request, $email_file);
        array_push($this->file_request, $email_file);
        
        Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('request_file',json_encode($this->file_request)));

        return response()->json([
            'name' => $this->file_request,
        ]);

        }catch(Exception $e){
            return $e;
        }

      
    }
```

Comment: Is your `$file_request` array empty, or is the cookie not being set?

Comment: This function store multiple file and I want to save all name file in file request array so if I send File number one it's push to array with no problem but when I send File number 2 it's push in array but replace file number one 
It's must the array file 1 and 2 not just last file

Comment: Are you sending multiple files in the same request, or separate requests? If you're sending separate requests you won't get the same instance of your controller each time.

Comment: Yes it's separate request

Comment: Then do you have any idea to solve this problem and get that same array from controller in each time

Comment: If all the files are related, send them in a single request.